# Python: Error while installing Numpy & Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, scipy

I am trying to install numpy, scipy and pandas but getting the following error:

```
Aleeshas-MacBook-Air:~ aleesha$ pip install numpy scipy pandas
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): numpy in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): scipy in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python
Collecting pandas
  Using cached pandas-0.19.1-cp27-cp27m-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.macosx_10_10_intel.macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pytz>=2011k in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python (from pandas)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): python-dateutil in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python (from pandas)
Installing collected packages: pandas
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/install.py", line 317, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_set.py", line 742, in install
    **kwargs
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_install.py", line 831, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_install.py", line 1032, in move_wheel_files
    isolated=self.isolated,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/wheel.py", line 346, in move_wheel_files
    clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/wheel.py", line 317, in clobber
    ensure_dir(destdir)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 83, in ensure_dir
    os.makedirs(path)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas'
You are using pip version 8.1.2, however version 9.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
Aleeshas-MacBook-Air:~ aleesha$
```

I have Python version  - `Python 3.5.2`. Why in the first place is pip trying to install at 2.7?

Comment: Try running the same command with `pip3`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you install Anaconda, with it you will solve a lot of issues. It supports the latest 3.5 version, comes equipped with most of the data analitics libraries and the ones you dont have you can get with pip install, which is guaranteed to work since pip get comes with Anaconda as well.